# Is it possible to build a custom deep learning layer for a neural network using ML.NET?

Tags: c#, matlab, deep-learning, ml.net

In MATLAB we can build our own [custom deep learning layers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/define-custom-deep-learning-layer.html) by defining forward and backward functions, but I'm just wondering if is that possible in C# using ML.NET?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe ML.NET supports forward and backward functions at the moment. For C#, you could probably use [Tensorflow.NET](https://github.com/SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET) for this instead.